# Remove dots(or period) from dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I want to remove dot or period from name of cities in my dataframe. For example

```
mydf <- data.frame(city1=c('New York','New York','Savanna la Mar','TokYo','Los Angeles','Memphis','Memphis','El Salvador','Cleveland','La Paz'),
                   city2=c('New.York','New.York','Chicago','Knoxville','Savanna.la.Mar','Tokyo','Los.Angeles','Chicago','El.Salvador','La.Paz'),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The typical data looks like. In city2, name of city with more than one word is separated by dot. I want to make it similar to city1.

```
mydf
            city1          city2
1        New York       New.York
2        New York       New.York
3  Savanna la Mar        Chicago
4           TokYo      Knoxville
5     Los Angeles Savanna.la.Mar
6         Memphis          Tokyo
7         Memphis    Los.Angeles
8     El Salvador        Chicago
9       Cleveland    El.Salvador
10         La Paz         La.Paz
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to do this:

```r
mydf$city2 <- gsub("[.]", " ", mydf$city2)

mydf
#>             city1          city2
#> 1        New York       New York
#> 2        New York       New York
#> 3  Savanna la Mar        Chicago
#> 4           TokYo      Knoxville
#> 5     Los Angeles Savanna la Mar
#> 6         Memphis          Tokyo
#> 7         Memphis    Los Angeles
#> 8     El Salvador        Chicago
#> 9       Cleveland    El Salvador
#> 10         La Paz         La Paz
```